# Automatic GitHub release from signed tag?

Tags: git, github, release, git-tag

I used to push lightweight tags into my GitHub repository and edit them into Releases with details of changes. This worked fine.

Now I started signing my tags, which means they are annotated rather than lightweight tags. I was hoping GitHub would consider them releases, so I put the same information I previously would have written on GitHub into the tag message.

However, GitHub does not consider it a release, only a tag. I can "draft a  new release" based on the tag as I did before, but I wonder if there is a way to get GitHub to automatically do that, using the information from the tag message.